# unix command line ...how to grep and show only file names that contain a string?

Tags: unix, command-line, grep

I know I can search for a string with:

```
grep -n -d recurse 'snoopy' *
```

and then it shows every file name and instance that contains that string, like:

```
file/name.txt:23    some snoopy here
file/name2.txt:59   another snoopy there
file/name2.txt:343  some more snoopy
etc...
```

The problem is that with many occurrences, the list is huge. How do I make it show only the actual file names that contain the string, without duplicates and without the occurrence?

Only like:

```
file/name1.txt
file/name52.txt
file/name28293.txt
```

Thanks a lot for any help :)

Comment: You use the `-l` argument.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `-l` flag (or, in both BSD and GNU `grep`, `--files-with-matches`) does what you want.

From [the POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/grep.html):

> Write only the names of files containing selected lines to standard output. Pathnames shall be written once per file searched. If the standard input is searched, a pathname of "(standard input)" shall be written, in the POSIX locale. In other locales, "standard input" may be replaced by something more appropriate in those locales.

Both BSD and GNU also explicitly guarantee that this will be more efficient. ([Older BSD](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/grep.1.html) versions say "… `grep` will only search a file until a match has been found, making searches potentially less expensive", [newer BSD](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=grep&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+11-current&arch=default&format=html) and [GNU](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) say "The scanning will stop on the first match".) If you don't know which `grep` you have and which options it has, just type `man grep` at the shell and you should get the manpage.

Comment: The `-l` option was in 7th Edition UNIX too, so it is essentially available everywhere.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Does the builtin `grep` in `busybox` and other similar all-in-one-micro-userlands have `-l`? I was trying to find docs, but every `busybox` machine I have has the builtin disabled and `/bin/grep` or `/usr/bin/grep` is the GNU version…

Comment: Accurate answer: I don't know.  However, to claim to be a built-in replacement for `grep`, it pretty much must support `-l`.  One reason for it being a separate executable is that there is probably too much code in `grep`.  That would be especially true if it contains multiple regex packages (PCRE plus the various other packages that tend to be included).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Yeah, I don't know, and don't want to search the source to `busybox` and all of its competitors. (At least `busybox` _does_ include `grep`, it just isn't enabled on most machines.) I think leaving it at "this is part of the POSIX requirements" gets the idea across that you should be able to count on it, together with your comment that strongly implies any pre-POSIX system ought to have it as well…